# threads is exiting my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to upload images to a php file, everything works, but sometimes when the site is

getting slow to load our app start frizzing until the page is done loading so i thought

about using threads to avoid such frizzing, but right now our app display and quit. I dont

see any warnings or problem... it just enter the app and exist right away. Please help me

out

the code:

```
-(void) source {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 80);

    NSString *urlString = @"http://domain";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    our_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", returnString];
}


-(void)som:(id)param{
    [lock lock];

    [lock unlock];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NSURLRequest in an asynch method, however if you want your current code to work follow these insturctions

First change this line

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(multithreading:) toTarget:  [MainViewController class] withObject:nil];
```

to

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(multithreading:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Second, you are updating the UI in a non UI thread, so wrap this

```
our_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", returnString];
```

around `dispatch_get_main_queue` like the following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    our_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", returnString];
});
```

Finally remove the locks since you are not really using them

```
    //[lock lock];
    [self source];
    //[lock unlock];
```

Comment: Halla fi Omar, i'm getting problems with: dispatch_async , maybe there is a typo?

Comment: I got it just change } to  });

Answer (score 2):

Totally wrong approach. Look carefully at the [documentation of NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and you will find the method sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:.

You will need to learn using blocks though (but it is worth it).

Comment: Agreed! Async is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to yan.kun's answer,

I suggest you to use third party library such as `AFNetworking` which has all the functionality to deal with Async operation which will be more easy to code and safe.

link : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/

Comment: Im going take a look +1 from me